# Can we use Google Fusion tables as data source for making a visualization using d3.js?

Tags: data-visualization, d3.js, google-fusion-tables

I do not have a web server and need to do a visualization using data driven documents (d3.js)

for a dataset that i have stored in Fusion tables. Is it possible to use intrinsic functions of d3.js or any other approach to visualize this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can export Fusion tables as CSV. D3 can read CSV data directly through the [`d3.csv` functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV).